# Dictionary won't update the value from a variable that was updated outside of the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pointers, variables

I have a dictionary that contains variables that are text. I want the dictionary to have the updated values of all the variables.However, when I update the variable, the dictionary still holds the old value.

For instance:

```
firstValue = "First Value Key"
secondValue = "Second Value Key"
thirdValue = "Third Value Key"

Dictionary = {"0":firstValue,
              "1":secondValue,
              "2":thirdValue}

print(Dictionary["0"])

firstValue = "New Value"

print(Dictionary["0"])
```

The output is the following:

```
First Value Key
First Value Key
```

But I want the output to look like this:

```
First Value Key
New Value
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The dictionary contains a reference to the _value_, not the _name_. Recommended reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score -1):

You're only changing the variable that you already passed into the dictionary, update the value directly to it:

```
Dictionary['0'] = "New Value"
```

Comment: You should use the variable value instead

Answer (score -1):

You need to assign the value of the variable to the dictionary value:

```
firstValue = "First Value Key"
secondValue = "Second Value Key"
thirdValue = "Third Value Key"

Dictionary = {"0":firstValue,
              "1":secondValue,
              "2":thirdValue}

print(Dictionary["0"])

firstValue = "New Value"
Dictionary["0"] = firstValue
print(Dictionary["0"])
```